# How to configure SQL Warehouse API settings persist with session in Azure Databricks?

Tags: sql, azure-databricks

I have my following statement to send in SQL Warehouse API

```
set use_cached_result = false; 
select 1;
```

But it only allowed inline statement and will show the error if I send it with

```json
{
    "statement": "set use_cached_result = false; select 1;"
}
```

> "message": "\n[INVALID_SET_SYNTAX] Expected format is 'SET', 'SET key', or 'SET key=value'. If you want to include special characters in key, or include semicolon in value, please use backquotes, e.g., SET `key`=`value`.(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nset use_cached_result = false; select 1;\n^^^\n"

I would like to test the sql statement with no cache hitting, but this setting only allowed per session in notebook. Do we have alternative?